# Can we sum values on X axis in HIstogram in R

Tags: r

I have a data set in r on which I am trying to create a histogram.

The variable on x axis I have is CR_DT i.e. date and on the x axis I need sum of weight i.e. `test$CHG_WT` on y axis. I tried researching a lot but could not find a solution hence request you all to please advice

```
CR_DT = c("13-Mar-15", "31-Mar-15", "15-Mar-15", "17-Mar-15")
CHG_WT = c(770,3730,70, 100,600,2000)
```

Hence I need sum of CHG_WT on CR_DT basis in histogram 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That makes sense only if CR_DT and CHG_WT have the same length and CR_DT some repetitions.

```
CR_DT = c("13-Mar-15", "31-Mar-15", "15-Mar-15", "17-Mar-15","15-Mar-15","13-Mar-15")
CHG_WT = c(770,3730,70, 100,600,2000)
CR_DTs=unique(CR_DT)
CHG_WTs=sapply(CR_DTs,function(d)sum(CHG_WT[CR_DT==d]))
barplot(CHG_WTs,names.arg = CR_DTs,col=rainbow(length(CHG_WTs)),cex.names = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Robert for the help this helped .